# Hourly time series plotting

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to plot the following hourly data. How can I change my data to an time series object? Was trying with the `xts` package but got an error message:

```
new_data <- structure(list(starttime = c("01.01.2015 00:00", "01.01.2015 01:00", 
"01.01.2015 02:00", "01.01.2015 03:00", "01.01.2015 04:00", "01.01.2015 05:00"
), Fossil = c(435, 434, 435, 436, 436, 436)), .Names = c("starttime", 
"Fossil"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

str(new_data)

$ starttime: chr  "01.01.2015 00:00" "01.01.2015 01:00" "01.01.2015 02:00"  "01.01.2015 03:00" ...
$ Fossil   : int  435 434 435 436 436 436 434 436 415 331

 head(new_data)
 starttime         Fossil
1 01.01.2015 00:00    435
2 01.01.2015 01:00    434
3 01.01.2015 02:00    435
4 01.01.2015 03:00    436
5 01.01.2015 04:00    436
6 01.01.2015 05:00    436

hnew_dataxts <- as.xts(x=new_data[,"Fossil"], order.by=new_data[,"starttime"])
colenames(hnew_dataxts) <- colnames(new_data)[-1]

    Error in xts(x, order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency, .CLASS = "integer",  : 
order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

Comment: What did you try with `xts`? Please share some code in your question. You need to first convert `starttime` to a date/time object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first convert the `starttime` column to a date/time object. You can use `strptime` function.

```
new_data$starttime <- strptime(new_data$starttime, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
hnew_dataxts <- xts(new_data[,"Fossil"], order.by=new_data[,"starttime"])

plot(hnew_dataxts)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to plot just hourly data without the date?